# every time i lex compile, i get a warning message says rule cannot be matched

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

i get it in line 39 which is the one of operand

```
 %option noyywrap
%{
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
chif [0-9]
let [a-z|A-Z]
entier {chif}+
id {let}(_?({let}|{chif})+)*
reel {chif}+,{chif}+
operand ({entier}|{id}|{reel})
%%
{id} {return(IDENT);}
{entier} {return(INT);}
{reel} {return(REEL);}
{operand} {return(OPR);}

. {yyerror();}
%%
```

i tried changing the rule `operand ({entier}|{id}|{reel})` to make it more specific and it didn't work, i also tried to change the placement and still nothing

Comment: `operand` is a disjunction of the three previous patterns, so any input that *could* match it, will have already marched one of the earlier ones. Unless you have a very specific use case, I don't think it makes sense to have `OPR` as a token type at all.

Comment: Exactly. It should be a production in the grammar. Not a lexical entity at all.